# jQuery span to input and vice-versa

Tags: jquery, input, live, html

I have a problem. Look at the code bellow:

```
   $(function () {
    $('span').live('click', function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'text',
                'name': 'aname',
                'value': $(this).html()
        });
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    });

    $('input').live('blur', function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
    });
    });
```

and html now:

```
<span>Click aici</span>
```

So, this it works, obviously, until jquery 1.8.3, inclusively. After 1.8.3 .live() is deprecated an we need to use .on(). So the code become:

```
$(function () {
    $('span').on('click', function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'text',
                'name': 'aname',
                'value': $(this).html()
        });
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    });

    $('input').on('blur', function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
    });
    });
```

or just:

```
$(function () {
    $('span').click(function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'text',
                'name': 'aname',
                'value': $(this).html()
        });
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    });

    $('input').blur(function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
    });
    });
```

But this is working just first time.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hW3vk/
So, any idea how to do that will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "first time"? If I alternate clicking on and off the text, it works fine.

Comment: works fine. Whats the problem...?

Comment: He means with the second code, not the .live code as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/hW3vk/4/

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that his fiddle still used the `.live()`.

Comment: It seems that I can not edit the question. So: first when I use .on() the input doesn't change back to span.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'span', function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'text',
                'name': 'unique',
                'value': $(this).html()
        });
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    });

    $(document).on('blur', 'input', function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

You need to change the `on` parameters in order for it to work as live does

```
$('(parent) static selector').on('event', 'dynamic selector', function(){...})
```

Instead of `$(document)` you can use a parent selector so it will narrow down the travel

Also here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/hW3vk/5/

Comment: That it is ! Thank you ! I will accept this answer in ... 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

I searched for this and found exactly the answer I wanted.

And then I discovered the "contenteditable" attribute, which supercedes the reasons I would want to change a span to an input using jQuery...

I don't know if this question & answer predates contentediable, but in case it does or might otherwise be helpful, all major browsers now support it, so the entire solution I needed was this:

```
<span contenteditable="true">Click aici</span>
```